# Error : "Category" declared as different kind of symbol in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have created my own classes Category.h and Category.m. Category class is inheriting NSObject. In my project there is only one class named Category.

At following line, it's showing me this error.

```
@interface Category : NSObject
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question is very vague. Can you provide some example code?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: "Category" declared as different kind of symbol in XCode 4

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you check the documentation there's Category type which is:

```
typedef struct objc_category *Category;
```

You are getting this error because `Category` is defined as a pointer to `struct objc_category`.

If you want to avoid these kind of errors I suggest you adding your own prefix to all the classes you make in the project. Either from your name:

- Your nickname: iAsh
- ClassPrefix: IA
- Example class: IACategory

or from project name:

- Project: Awesome Project;
- Class prefix: AP
- Example class: APCategory

Also double-checking with documentation is always good. It's very rare that you'll hit existing class, but possible.

Comment: Eimantas: Can you tell me how can i search for any word to ensure that it is allowed to use? Is there any section which provides this information ? I am searching for this.

Comment: Just open up the documentation and enter your searchable keyword into search  field. Also don't forget to tweak search parameters by docset (iOS/Mac OS X) and match (exact, containing, etc.) clause.